# Getting the minimal height of UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

i'm adding the tableview of a UITableViewController as a subview of my custom view.

Therefore i need to find out the height of the (grouped, scrolling-disabled) tableview, in other words the added heights of:  **all cells + sectionHeaders + headers + padding.**

The height property always returns 430pts :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `UITableView` is subclass of `UIScrollView`, you can get its 'content size' via:

```
tableView.contentSize
```

and then you can get the height via:

```
tableView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: thanks, i thought so too, but oddly my "tableView.contentSize.height" is (null)!

Comment: I found a solution, but it's pretty ugly:  
The several drawing rects are available as properties of the tableview. (e.g. `rectForSection`)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I used to make this work with my TableViewController.

Simply implement `- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover` as follows:

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover {
    NSInteger height = 0;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
        height = height + [self.tableView rectForSection:i].size.height;
    }

    return CGSizeMake(320, height);
}
```

I just returned a width of 320 because that worked nicely in the UIPopoverController I was trying to display the TableView inside.